# read context.xml from outer war

Tags: java, jar, war

I found several similar topics, like reading from inner structure etc, however it still does not solve my problem.

Project structure:

- whole project -> war, which has:

  several jar's connected as dependency
  in pom.xml;

  context.xml in META-INF folder, which I need to read from one of jars.
- part of it -> jar, which is dependency in war's pom.xml

**I've tried a few solutions like:**

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/context.xml");
```

However I did not expect that to work as I think my jar searches for this resource in its structure, not in war.

I need **jar project** to read **context.xml** from **war project**. So, **jar** is like inner structure and **war** is outer. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With getResourceAsStream() you have access to all resources in the classpath.
The classpath of a webapplication consists of every jar under WEB-INF/lib and every file under WEB-INF/classes

META-INF is not in the classpath.

Please read the question: [How to get resource from the context.xml file in tomcat webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298132/how-to-get-resource-from-the-context-xml-file-in-tomcat-webapp)